# Graph shifts position when adding plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, pgfplotstable

If I compile this code without the Gaussian function at the end everything is allright, but if I try with it the whole figure shifts to the right.

In this example it is not a very big problem, but in my original code I need the graph to be bigger and when adding the Gaussian half the graph is off the page. 
I tried some stuff that worked with other floating objects but nothing seemed to work.

```
    \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}
    {
        \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%Gauss #2=sigma; #1=phi
    }

\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstableread
    {
        d
        10.35053421
        11.81898404
        12.89666307
        11.28088572
        12.35758085
        11.80645398
    }\datatableA

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}
      \addplot[
      hist={
        data min = 10,
        data max = 13,
      },
      bar direction = y,
      ] table [        
        y = d,
      ] {\datatableA};
      \addplot [domain = 0:18, ]{gauss(12,3)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you declare the function, there are spurious spaces that are being created (so the problem is not the plot itself). I marked the space with a dot:

```
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}
{.
    \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}
```

If you delete all spaces from your function definition at the end of the line and add `%` immediately after the curly bracket, you'll eliminate the problem. You can safely tab the inner command, it still won't matter. So here's the correct version (I personally indent and place the curly brackets differently, but using the same symbol with your code works):

```
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{% <--- add this
    \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! Didn't know about that at all. Now everything is fine.

Comment: @user104482 No problem. I just added to my answer that you can indent/tab commands as you like but if you see weird shifts like that, it's likely that somewhere in the command definition there are spaces, so just check it again line by line.

Comment: the spaces at the beginning of a line are ignored. Spaces at the end are the problematic ones

Comment: @percusse Oh even without the symbol? That makes sense.

Comment: You are missing one more at the end of the code line too ;)

Comment: @percusse Where? There was only one space after the bracket.

Comment: I've added them